# How to use DBFile in cms SS4

Tags: silverstripe-4

I have been attempting to use the new DBFile datatype as in this (pruned) example

```
class SlideImage extends DataObject
{
  private static $table_name = 'SlideImage';
  private static $plural_name = 'Slide Images';
  private static $singular_name = 'Slide Image';

  private static $db = array(
        'Name' => 'Varchar(255)',
         'TestImageField' => "DBFile('image/supported')"
  );
  private static $has_one = array(
        'Image' => Image::class,
 );
```

The Image is easy to deal with in the function getCMSFields(){

```
  $imageField = new UploadField('Image', 'Choose Image');
  $imageField->setFolderName('Uploads/promotionalbanners');
```

and the new 
      $imageField = Injector::inst()->create(FileHandleField::class, 'Image','Choose Image');

works as well.

However, attempting to use either of those with the TestImageField as in the attempts below produces the error "Cannot use object of type SilverStripe\Assets\Storage\DBFile as array"

```
  $fields->addFieldToTab('Root.Main', new UploadField('TestImageField', 'Choose Image'));
```

or perhaps

```
  $imageFielddb = Injector::inst()->create(FileHandleField::class, 'TestImageField');

  $imageFielddb = $this->TestImageField->scaffoldFormField('TestImageField');
```

I know I am doing something really stupid around the concept of DBFile in the db definition but how can I used that as an actual image reference - or can I not on its own?

Comment: https://docs.silverstripe.org/en/4/developer_guides/files/file_management/#loading-content-into-dbfile  . Could it be that you are assuming that UploadField can talk directly with the DBFile. Rather than using uploadfield youd need to set the PATH what file it should use. Havent played with that yet my self.